# Codeigniter Validation is not working , page is redirecting to blank page

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm new in codeigniter . Both of these pages location are  correct . I guess there is some code to activate form_validator for the view page .

edit : i have added

```
          if ($this->form_validation->run()){
$this->load->view('home');
    }else{
  $this->load->view('login');
      }
```

the above code in the controller still it's redirecting page to blank page

```
   <?php  

 class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
  function __construct()
    {
        parent:: __construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url', 'html'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');               
         $this->load->database();

    }
public function index()
{       
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','username', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[15]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','email', 'trim|required|valid_email');


         $this->form_validation->run();
    $this->load->view('login');
 {



   }
   }
   ?>
```

and here is view page . I also used pure html form tag instead of form_open method , but it also didn't worked , It redirected me to same page and didn't displayed any error

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
             <html lang="en">
             <head>
                    <meta charset="utf-8">
                      <title>Welcome to CodeIgniter</title>
                       </head>
                        <body>
                        <div id="container">
<?php echo validation_errors('form'); ?>
<?php echo form_open('form'); ?>

 <?php echo form_error('username');  ?>
 <input type='text' name ='username' >
 <?php echo form_error('email');  ?>
 <input type='email' name='email'>

 <input type="submit" value='go'>
  </form>
  </div>

      </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

**In View** [Link to Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36573070/codeigniter-validation-is-not-working-page-is-redirecting-to-blank-page/36573170?noredirect=1#comment60745152_36573170)

```
<?php echo form_open('welcome'); ?>
```

**In Controller**

```
public function index()
{       
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','username', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[15]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','email', 'trim|required|valid_email');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        # Fail
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
    else
    {
        # Success
        $this->load->view('home'); # Load your contrller 
    }
}
```

[Check this Tutorial as well](http://www.formget.com/form-validation-using-codeigniter/)

Comment: I tried . Still didn't worked :(
You can try this it'll not work

Comment: `<?php echo form_open('form'); ?>` is your controller name is form ??

Comment: After submit it redirects me to "about:blank"

Comment: see the last line of controller
 "$this->load->view('login');"

Comment: @SumitBhatia No. This comes after submit the page. I mean first time how you load. Post the controller code of that

Comment: welcome.php is located in controller directory . When i go to root directory it's automatically redirects to welcome page of controller directory . I already put the code of welcome.php . the login.php is in view directory .

Comment: @SumitBhatia i Can guess whats wrong. [Check this link](http://www.formget.com/form-validation-using-codeigniter/)

Comment: In login page I checked the forms property through inspect element . This is what i see 
https://s9.postimg.org/azmn9tesf/action.png

Comment: and when i change action property to "http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/welcome3"
it works fine

Comment: ah got it. Go to **config.php** and **set `base_url`**

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
if ($this->form_validation->run()){
    $this->load->view('home');
}else{
      $this->load->view('login');
}
```

Comment: your answer would be more helpful if you explained WHY it should work.

Answer (score 0):

change the the complete body of index function as it is bellow

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','username','required|min_length[5]|max_length[15]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','email','trim|required|valid_email');

    if($this->form_validation->run()){
        $this->load->view('home');
    }else{
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
} else {
    $this->load->view('login');
}
```